# Can we able to Edit/Create a file using 'File Permission'?

Tags: permissions, privileges

Is there any Way to Edit/Create a file in the method of **File Permission** ?

Suppose it is **'7'** means can we able to change it to **'4'** ?

i.e **-rwx** to **-r** ?

Is there any code or___ to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `chmod`. This command allows you to change permissions for a file.

Say you want to change the permissions of ./foo.txt to '**4**' then it's `chmod 4 ./foo.txt`

If you want to do this to all the files in a directory it would be `chmod 4 *`.

If you wanted to do this recursively through all files and directories somewhere it would be `chmod -R 4 *`

If you wanted to revert the change back to '*7*' on a file, it would be `chmod 7 ./foo.txt`. You can also use * or -R this way to change permissions on more than one file.

[Click here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/chmod.1.html) for the `chmod` man pages.

Occasionally you will need to run `sudo chmod` instead of just `chmod`. Originally I had it as `sudo chmod` everywhere, however it is a bad habit to get into to use `sudo` when you don't need to.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! ,Thanks a lot @ Eric power. But can we able to do it to all the files and how to revert it ..?

Comment: I edited my answer, is that what you mean?

Comment: -1: `chmod` doesn't always need `sudo`.

Comment: thanks to all.. I mean if we don't know the chmod of a file but we have changed it ! Can we able to revert it @ Eric Power?

Comment: Hmm, not that I'm aware. I believe you would have to write a script that would check the permissions and save them somewhere, and then when you want to revert them read from wherever you saved it and revert to that level.

Comment: @EricPower Good answer but how about addind a link tho the chmod manpage ?

Comment: Sure, although I typically use the `man chmod` command.

Comment: Sure, just noob friendly to add link, I like this now +1

Comment: Good point, I'll start doing that from now on.

Comment: @markkirby in that case, link to the Ubuntu manpages, since these are generated from the packages available for Ubuntu. For `chmod`, it might not make much difference, but for other commands, it could.